# "Effect" vs. "Affect"

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

I've noticed that some people use *effect* and *affect* interchangeably. What are the differences between these two and when are the proper situations to use each of them?

Comment: It's interesting that this is tagged as a homophone, since I personally pronounce, affect as /a'fekt/ whereas I pronounce "effect" as /ɪːfekt/. Of course, this varies widely by region. That is, I have a short "ah" sound in "affect", and a long "ee" sound in "effect".

Comment: @Vincent I rolled it back, there should be a better tag for these kind of questions. I couldn't come up with anything interesting. Any ideas?

Comment: I admit, my pronunciation suffers because I speak too quickly, but for the most part, I've heard "effect" and "affect" pronounced with the same "uh" sound.

Comment: I said it was interesting, not that it was wrong. Homophones very often depend on the accent of the speaker. For instance, on "affect", 99% of people don't use the /a/ sound, but I do. I think homophone is indeed an appropriate tag.

Comment: Relevant: http://xkcd.com/326/

Comment: Should offer a reward for anyone posting a useful sentence containing all four variations (two nouns, two verbs) used correctly.

Comment: This question is six years old and has several answers that will be useful to visitors. Let's not close it merely because we were less insistent on research in the question six years ago.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The noun is usually "effect" -- unless in more formal or literary contexts in which case "affect" as a noun can mean feeling or emotion.

The verb is generally "affect", although "effect" is possible if the meaning is "put into place" or "carry out".

Here are some example sentences:

"His plans had no effect on me."

"His disconsolate eyes brought on a sad affect."

"His plans affected me."

"He effected a plan to change the world."

Comment: +1 for bringing up affect as a noun, fascinating word, hard to get your mind around what it actually means, like reading Heidegger or something: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affect_%28psychology%29

Comment: Yep, each word can be used as both a noun and a verb and 3 of the 4 uses are related to the same concept, causation.

No wonder people get confused: It's confusing!

Comment: "His plans had no effect on me." and "His plans affected me." seem like the same sentence, except for whether or not "me" was impacted. I still don't know what to do. Any more help?

Comment: Jeff - In the first sentence, *effect* is a noun, in the second sentence, *affected* is a verb. The sentences effectively have the same meaning.

Comment: I was ready to slam the latest edition of the AP Stylebook for going soft on the distinction between "affect" and "effect", but it's not that simple, see https://www.arcticllama.com/blog/writing-tips/grammar/affect-vs-effect-ap-style/.

Unfortunately, most of my colleagues in the corporate world have given up and just use "affect" for every occasion.

Comment: I was trying to draw a mathy type diagram to both remind and clarify the differences of the two words just now… and gave up. Joined this stack as an side-effect, good result, I'm less of the sad affect/effect.

Answer (score 24):

The ["common errors" site](https://brians.wsu.edu/2016/05/16/affect-effect/) mentions 3 different meanings for affect (verb):

> - When “affect” is accented on the final syllable (a-FECT), it is usually a verb meaning “**have an influence on**”:
>
>   “The million-dollar donation from the industrialist
>   did not affect my vote against the Clean Air Act.”
> - “**to make a display of or deliberately cultivate.**”
>   Occasionally a pretentious person is said to affect an artificial air of sophistication.
>   Speaking with a borrowed French accent or ostentatiously wearing a large diamond ear stud might be an affectation.
> - “**emotion**.” (when the word is accented on the first syllable (AFF-ect)).
>   In this case the word is used mostly by psychiatrists and social scientists—people who normally know how to spell it.
>
> […]
>
> When you *affect* a situation, you have an *effect* on it.
>
> Less common is a verb meaning “**to create**” (to cause to come into being):
>
> “I’m trying to effect a change in the way we purchase widgets.”

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/effect) details:

> The verb effect goes beyond mere influence; it refers to actual achievement of a final result.

Comment: Now I think I am even *more* confused!

Comment: So I *think* an easy to use rule is: If it is a think (noun) or means 'to create', then use "effect", else use "affect". Anyone comments from the experts out there?

Answer (score 3):

The rule that *mostly works* it this:
affect = verb, think "a" for action, wheras
effect = noun, the result of the action

to remember: 
"a" comes before "e" in the alphabet, and you must affect something to cause an effect

Comment: Unfortunately, there is both a noun and a verb 'affect' and a noun and a verb 'effect'!

Answer (score 1):

Here’s a quick informal technique for you: If it is not easy for you to remember that that the word “affect” is most commonly used as a verb while “effect” is usually used as a noun, then label this confusion as “aven.” It sounds like amen. The “av” in aven should make you recall affect as verb and the “en” is effect as noun.

Source: [A Snappy Guide to Differentiating “Affect” and “Effect”](http://www.englishgrammar.org/affect-effect/)