# Did CBS make a spelling mistake?

Tags: orthography

I am not a native English speaker, but the recently uploaded video on the CBS News channel seems to contain a typo in the title.

> How will "October surprises" **effect** the polls?

[image: Cropping of the issue]

I have seen *effect* used as a verb, but I am fairly confident that *affect* would be the right choice in this case.

Comment: Yes, this is a typo. It will, no doubt, be corrected.

Comment: You are correct. It should be *affect*. It is a common error that many native English speakers make.

Comment: Right. It's not a grammar error, however. It's a spelling error. Spelling has nothing to do with grammar, which comes from spoken language. Illiterate English speakers still know English grammar, even if they can't spell anything.

Comment: @JohnLawler Heh, I just fixed that. I seem to mention it daily.

Comment: @JohnLawler It's not obvious to me that it's a spelling error. It could also be an error in word choice resulting from a lack of understanding of the difference between the meanings of the verbs *affect* and *effect*. If the latter, could it not be a grammatical error? After all, many grammatical errors result from incorrect word choices.

Comment: Motivation is irrelevant; what manifests is the difference in spelling. In language the two words are pronounced identically, and probably for many speakers there simply is no difference; the spelling difference is artificial and exists only in writing.

Comment: @JohnLawler: I don't pronounce them the same, and apparently (checking some dictionaries: [1](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/effect_2), [2](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/pronunciation/american/effect_2)) I'm not the only one. (I do see that some people do apparently pronounce them the same.)

Comment: @JohnLawler I don't pronounce them the same - but then I may be eccentric in so far as I am British.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably a mistake. Either this is a typographical error or someone at CBS needs to pick up their game.

As [Oxford Dictionaries explains](https://web.archive.org/web/20220823025949/https://www.lexico.com/grammar/affect-or-effect), **affect** is a verb while **effect** is usually a noun.

> **Affect** is chiefly used as a verb and its main meaning is ‘to influence or make a difference to’, as in the following example sentences:
>
> *The pay increase will greatly affect their lifestyle.*

While **effect** can be used as a verb (see below) in this circumstance, **affect** should have been used.

> When used as a verb **effect** means ‘to bring something about as a result’. It’s most often used in a formal context as oppose to everyday English:
>
> *The prime minister effected many policy changes.*
>
> The key thing to remember is that effect is most commonly used as a noun, whereas affect is typically used as a verb.

Comment: The very article you linked to mentions that _effect_ is also used as a verb.

Comment: @mafagafogigante I have noted that in an edit. :)

Comment: *This is **probably** a mistake!?* Nothing like hedging your bets!

Comment: @FumbleFingers Well I thought that since my citation does note that it can be used as a verb I ought be be conservative here. Perhaps a little over the top :)

Comment: I suppose you could just about say *We will effect a poll*, but I reckon you'd have to be pretty good at lateral thinking to contrive a context where "October surprises" could cause multiple polls. I'm afraid I hastily closevoted for lack of prior research, but it's no surprise to me now to find that [“Effect” vs. “Affect”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/315/) has been quietly garnering votes for over 5 years with even less evidence of the OP having looked anything up.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes, the question to which you link lacks prior research but now acts as good reference material so it is probably acceptable.

Comment: @BernardoSulzbach however, the verb definition of *effect* does not apply here. The OP's quotation is not asking whether "October surprises" will "bring about" the polls.

Comment: The election was going to happen in November even if there weren't any surprises in October, so they couldn't effect it.