# The affect of less milk, fewer bottles

Tags: grammar

I used to say the phrase "less milk, fewer bottles" to force myself to learn when to correctly use less/fewer.

Does anyone have any similar memory/learning trick to assist with effect/affect?

I'm now unsure about the title of this question :( 
I've tried, on and off, for some years to fully understand this - but my stupid head will not comply.

And I have read this ["Effect" vs. "Affect"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/315/effect-vs-affect) but I'm still confused!

Comment: The very last answer in "Effect" vs. "Affect" (provided by @user270475) does, in fact, provide a useful mnemonic to help you remember the common usage of these words.

Comment: He effected a move which affected his opponent. A strong effect may effect (bring about, cause) a sad affect. Not sure, but I hope it helps. :)

Comment: @Lucian “Strong leadership effects great affect; weak leadership greatly affects effect” might work too.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, I find yours better, so I upvoted it.:)