# Affect vs effect use

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, confusables

I am tangled with the problem of using affect /effect.

In an experiment,

The defocusing of projector lens blurs the projected images that are projected onto an object.The projected images are used to generate the shape of the object using a method X.

Now I want opinion regarding these cases

1. Projected images are effected/affected by defocusing
2. The defocusing of images further effects/affects the method X.
3. The method X is effected/affected by defocusing.
4. The defocusing of projected images further effects/affects object's shape.

Comment: What does a dictionary say?

Comment: Without knowing the intended meaning for your sentences it’s impossible to say.  For example In sentence 1.  Are you saying that you are creating the projected images by defocusing or are you saying that the projected images are changed by the defocusing?

Comment: When the projector lens is moved to out of focus position it's called defocusing.. This defocusing just like our movie projectors blurs the projected image

Comment: Yes the projected images are changed by defocusing

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Effect" vs. "Affect"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/315/effect-vs-affect)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Cambridge:

> [**affect (v)**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/affect): to have an influence on someone or something, or to cause a change in someone or something
>
> **[effect (v)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/effect)**: to achieve something and cause it to happen

So, I would say you should use affect in each of your examples:

> Images are **affected** by defocusing.
>
> Defocusing **affects** images.
>
> Defocusing **affects** image's shape.
>
> Method is **affected** by defocusing.

You could use **effect** in a sentence such as the following:

> Defocusing **effects** (that is, *brings about* or *causes*) the desired fuzziness in the photographic image.

Comment: So what if defocusing causes blurring of image generated by method X. Will it be"defocusing effects image recontruction in Method X??"

Answer (score 0):

In your use case scenario:
Affect is a verb:  "Doing X will affect Y."
Effect is a noun: "The effect of doing X can easily be seen in the change in Y."

An easy exercise for learning the different use cases would be to replace these homophones in the following way to see if they make sense:

Replace "affect" with "cause a change in": Doing X will *cause a change in* Y. 
 Replace "effect" with "result": "The *result* of doing X can easily be seen in the change in Y."

Comment: These tend to be the more common usages, but it's far from absolute that effect is always a noun and affect is always a verb. Effect can be used as a verb, meaning to cause something. Similarly, affect can be used as a noun, meaning the outward display of one's emotions. The tip about seeing what replacement word fits still works, though.