# Effected vs affected

Tags: meaning

In a case study

Scattering of light affects the image captured by camera.

Now how to write

The scattering **affected** image...

Or

The Scattering **effected** image...

And

Image **affected** by scattering

Or 
Image **effected** by scattering...

Which one is correct?

Comment: Also https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/315/effect-vs-affect

Comment: And this recent post: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/532858/affect-vs-effect-use/533181#533181

Comment: Hi need a bit more clarification for the case when it's the other way around, e.g., I read somewhere:  if A affects B, then B is effected by A. So my question is based on this and I'm stuck

Comment: No, "B is effected by A" if "A causes B to happen" (= "A brings about B"), not if "A has an effect on B" (= "A affects B")

Comment: Hi thank you it clears many things, So in case underwater scattering affects an image (make it blur) then can I call the images "scattering affected images"?