# Resultant of a vector

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context, sentence

I have a **vector of values** and an **operator** affects these values by randomly adding small values in all of them.

Now when I refer to my resultant vector, is it correct to say:`operator effected values`
Because the operator has an effect on the values.

Hope it's not operator affected values

Hope my joining of this forum helps.

Comment: Welcome! Please see [“Effect” vs. “Affect”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/315/effect-vs-affect).

Comment: Hey guys,Thanks, such a lively community, good to see.

Comment: Some what..its as confusing as my question though

Comment: What is a **vector of values**? It's an unfamiliar phrase. I don't get the *of values* part. Why not simply *vector*? The operator would then add to the original vector a "small" vector of random magnitude and direction. You could say that the operator adds a small quantity to each *coordinate* or *component* of the vector. In any event, I agree with @LPH: you'd have to use operator-affected values, and, as indicated, I would use a hyphen. Your hope notwithstanding, there's nothing objectionable about it.

Comment: I'd go with *perturbed* in this case. "The perturbed vector ...". And I agree that you should just refer to the vector, which is understood to be the set of values. "Dither" is another possibility. It has formal technical usage. But in the case of dither, you probably do want to reference the elements, not the vector.

Comment: @PhilSweet Dither? I have read a lot of math books and I can honestly say that the term has yet to come up. If you frequently need to keep referring back to the vector which results from another vector after the randomizing operator(WLOG, say delta) has been applied to it, and/or the resulting vector's component values then for the sake of being explicitly clear just give it a name like V_delta or {v_delta_0,v_delta_1,...}.

Comment: @PhilSweet, I guess I stand corrected https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/4874524.pdf . Thank you for that; however please be careful with Dither in general usage since your audience may be unfamiliar with it and require a lead-up.

Comment: thanks guys for the reinforcement on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"To effect" means "to make happen", so that would be saying that the vector makes the values happen, which is not idioamtic; it is rather nonsensical. There are several possibilities.

- values randomly changed by an operator  (*"operator updated values" does not sound as if it were well defined*)
- values randomly modified by an operator
- values randomly conditioned by an operator
- values randomly affected by an operator

"Affected" would be the right term; however, the compound "operator affected values" does not appear to be idiomatic; there would have to be a definition in the text of what that means.

Comment: Hey LPH thank you for your reply. Can I write as "**the affected** values are further used" as they were affected by the operator.

Comment: @Sam It seems that a complement is needed after used: "used for…", used in …",  "used to …etc.

Comment: Oh yeah, but I mean to say that the values can be referred onwards as the "affected values", For example : Further division of the affected values. --_ Scientific document it is.

Comment: @Sam Yes, there seems to be no problem.